# javascript, making a side

Tags: javascript, object, sidebar

I want to make a sidebar that dynamically create content from an object result in javascript

```
Object { Chemistry: Array[3], Maths: Array[1], Physics: Array[2] }
```

And also there are some element in Array above

Comment: Not clear, also tell us what you have tried so far...

Comment: I want it to be like:
Table of content :
   chemistry:
     then some element from the array

Comment: and the questions is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this isn't the best way to do it, but this is an idea on how to make it:

```js
var obj = {'Chemistry':['Chemistry1','Chemistry2','Chemistry3'],'Maths':['Maths1'],'Physics':['Physics1','Physics2']};

function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function ulCreator(obj){
  var menu = document.createElement("UL");
  for (var key in obj) {
      var node = document.createElement("LI");
      var textnode = document.createTextNode(isNumber(key) ? obj[key] : key);
      node.appendChild(textnode);
      
      if(Array.isArray(obj[key])){
        node.appendChild(ulCreator(obj[key]));
      }
      menu.appendChild(node);
  }
  return menu;
}

document.getElementById("main").appendChild(ulCreator(obj));
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
```